Advice on migrating mysql columns from hexed char(24) to binary(12)
I have many mysql tables in production which uses char(24) as primary key. We use BSON ObjectId to create GUIDs (It's similar to UUIDv1, but it's smaller (12 bytes)).
currently, we store these 12-byte length ids as char(24) hex strings and we want to migrate  to binary(12)
This is a large production db (+100M rows), so I can't lock the database for more than couple of minutes.
I don't have any specific problems (like slow queries) right now. The database I'm working on is rapidly growing, and I want to ensure the design is in an optimal state. If I need to do this migration, it's better to do it today because it will be much harder and riskier in the future

What is your question, exactly?

you must shutdown for Maintenance and the do you change

What is the real goal?  (There may be a different solution.)  Meanwhile, are those char(24) values hexadecimal?  (That is, [0-9A-F]?)

How many tables are involved?  (You will essentially have to change all tables during the same downtime.)

@RickJames My goal is to reduce storage size and potentially increase performance. Since char(24) allocates at least 24 bytes, but binary(12) only uses 12 bytes, this seems like a reasonable refactoring to me.

@RickJames
there are ~10 tables, but I can refactor them one by one. the joins between these table are limited. so the number of tables are not really a big concern to me.

@RickJames > are those char(24) values hexadecimal?
Yes, but lowercase (0-9a-f)

My goal is to reduce storage size and potentially increase performance. Since char(24) allocates at least 24 bytes, but binary(12) only uses 12 bytes You forget about blocks. For example, if average row size is 256 bytes, a block size is 8 kb, and fill factor is 0.9 then average completely filled block stores 28 rows. If you save 12 bytes with your modification then average completely filled block will store 30 rows. And saved size will be ~ 7%... In practice the saved storage size will be less, up to zero maybe. Do you think that this is reasonable? Disk space is very cheap right now.

@Akina In one of my tables, the avg_row_size is currently 158 bytes. If I migrate the CHAR(24) columns to BINARY(12), I could reduce the avg_row_size from 158 bytes to 110 bytes.
Is it worth it?

I think that you'd save not more than 10% of the table size (while compare with the table size after OPTIMIZE). And the more inserts/deletions/updates are performed, the smaller the size difference will become.

I have a Rule of Thumb -- If the guestimate of the savings (speed/space/whatever) is less than 10%, don't bother.  Especially if it involves an unacceptable downtime.

And don't forget the app code that will have to change simultaneously with the DB changes.  Big risk.

Why do you feel that reducing the size of the data will have any great benefit?
Unless you're pulling the entire dataset across the network and processing it all client-side, the size of the data shouldn't matter that much.
Ten tables and 100M rows?  That's really not that big.
If you're having specific performance problems, identify them and tackle them.
Hoping to get performance benefits by shrinking the data just sounds wrong to me.
Don't "hope" or "guess" for performance benefits.  Test for them!
Use your Test database to try this out without disrupting your Production system.  Remember, this change might actually make things worse!
In the "Test" system, measure your application performance, then change the fields (which will require downtime, because you have to break all the foreign keys to do it) then measure performance again.
Personally, though, I doubt you'll see much difference.
Also, bear in mind that these fields might get shown to Users.
If that's the case, then you not only have to change the database, but the Application as well.  Binary fields might well be shown as just some "binary garbage".  Cue Bug Reports.

Yes, let's see the slowest query.  There may be a different solution that would give an even better performance boost.  (Such as a composite INDEX.)

@phill-w I don't have any specific problems (like slow queries) right now. The database I'm working on is rapidly growing, and I want to ensure the design is in an optimal state. If I need to do this migration, it's better to do it today because it will be much harder and riskier in the future.

@ERFANIUM Sorry, but this sounds like "Premature Optimisation" to me.
If you have a lot of fields in your records, the overhead around each of those might well outweigh the saving you'd make here.  Long story short, databases like having /lots/ of disk space.  It's just the nature of the beast and trying to force them to live in a smaller place will just "upset" them.  You've not said how big your database is, but 100M rows isn't that big, really.
